# Jenkins windows Gui gives an error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, jenkins, tomcat8

I have installed Apache Tomcat as windows services and deployed Jenkins( placed jenkins.war in webapps folder). - Windows Server 
In 'Execute Windows batch command' start mspaint.exe
When I build the job, I am getting service interactive detection dialog box.

If I disable the 'Allow service to interact with desktop' in tomcat service.

The build console says-Process leaked file descriptors. See https://jenkins.io/redirect/troubleshooting/process-leaked-file-descriptors for more information.

I need to open the mspaint.exe windows execution without human interaction, when I build the job in jenkins